# Is this correct about Jasmine's word order?

Tags: jasmine

In my newbie understanding, Jasmine provide this syntax below:

```
describe('FooBar', function(){
  it('should blah-blah', function(){
    expect('actual').toEqual('expect');
  });
});
```

expect('actual').toEqual('expect');
This order and words causes my confusion. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Your question title order and words causes me confusion.  Can you please rewrite so we can understand it?

Comment: The code you've pasted looks fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. To rephrase:

```
...
expect("result").toEqual("expected");
...
```